# How to use FB.api() for one given user

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-apps

I want to be able to display a list of my most recent facebook posts although I want only my posts to be seen not the posts of a logged in user. Instead of using FB.api("/me/posts") I want to just use my user ID statically instead of the current logged in user.

Comment: /me is "your user". what user id would you want to use? where did you get it?

Comment: This is not really possible using client-side code. Even if you made users login to your app first, so that you could use their user access token, using that you won’t be able to read just anyone’s posts (not sure if that was even possible any more if those users were actually friends with you on Facebook.) Since you will have to use your own access token then, this does not belong on the client side to begin with - expose your token there, and everyone could steal it. So if anything, you  will have to do this on the server side.